# Bone rotation skews geometry

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

The problem is self explanatory
[image: the problem]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f48syr0p0honsj7/gunlocker.blend?dl=0

Comment: Try applying scale to the dangly thing.

Comment: The dangly thing is part of the entire model and the scale has been applied to it.

Comment: Is the scale of the model (1, 1, 1) ?

Comment: Yes it is (1, 1, 1)

Comment: How do the mesh and the bone depend on each other?

Comment: Is the bone the only bone vert group all the verts in dangly thing are assigned too with weight 1.0? (i'm assuming you are using armature modifier, rather than bone parenting)

Comment: I am using the armature modifier and the dangly thing is a vertex group attached to the bone at weight 1.0. The bone is also parented to another bone using the bone group system but the same problem occurs without the parent.

Comment: check if there is another bone that has weight assigned to the same mesh as well, because if that is the case, the the result is a mix of the two bone's influences

Comment: That is true I actually have a bone for the entire dangly thing and knob then a bone for just the knob. I just noticed I can probably parent the knob to the handle bone and see if it works brb.

Comment: OK, I fixed the vertex groups but the problem still persists. I uploaded the blend file in Dropbox there if anybody wants to take a look at it.

Comment: I can't rotate the bone in pose mode and I also pressed alt+a, but results in something else

Comment: I had to use the parameters in the N menu in the top right to rotate anything for some reason, try it

Comment: I cannot modify the weight paint and vertex groups for some reason

Comment: I did lock the vertex groups which wont let you edit them, if you click on the lock symbol next to them in edit mode you should be able to modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh has 2 vertex groups that deform the exact same area with the exact same weight, causing this weird stretching to happen. Simply fix this by removing the "knob" selected area from the "gunlockerdoor" vertex group (unlocking the vertex groups first, of course.)

[image: gif]